# Zeroth left derived functor of right exact functor

Tags: homological-algebra

I have some difficulty understanding the following proof ([source](http://therisingsea.org/notes/DerivedFunctors.pdf)):

**Claim**:  If $T: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is a right exact functor of two Abelian categories, then $L_0 T$ and $T$ are canonically naturally equivalent.

**Proof**: Take a projective resolution $P_\bullet$ of some object $A\in \mathcal{A}$. Then we have an exact sequence $P_1 \rightarrow P_0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$. As $T$ is assumed right exact, we have an exact sequence $TP_1 \rightarrow TP_0 \rightarrow TA \rightarrow 0$. **Hence** $H_0(TP_\bullet)\simeq TA$.

My difficulty is seeing this final conclusion. I could prove that this was indeed true for the more specific case of R-Modules, but there I used the first isomorphism theorem, which I'm not sure if exists in an arbitrary Abelian category. Could you please explain *carefully* how the above equivalence follows from all of this?

**Edit** A category C is abelian if it is 1) additive, 2) for every monomorphism $f: A \rightarrow B$ the pair $(A,f)$ is the kernel of the epimorphism $B \rightarrow coker f$, 3) For every epimorphism $f: A\rightarrow B$ the pair $(f,B)$ is a cokernel of the monomorphism $ker f \rightarrow A$.

Comment: Of course we have the first isomorphism theorem, it's part of the definition of abelian category !

Comment: @Max, hm I didn't know about that. Could you point me to some expository materials that spell this out in detail?

Comment: Well from what wikipedia tells me, different people have different definitions; but see here for instance : http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ggim/S14-212lecturenote.pdf  Anyway, the point is that "$A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact" implies that "$\mathrm{coker}(A\to B)\to C$ is an isomorphism"

Comment: @EricTowers: C is abelian if 1) additive, 2) for any epi $A \rightarrow B$ the pair $(B,f)$ is a cokernel of the morphism $ker(f) \rightarrow A$, 3) for any mono $f: A \rightarrow B$ the pair $(A,f)$ is the kernel of the morphism $B \rightarrow coker(f)$.

Comment: @EricTowers just added